# What headers do I need to set for the Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services

I was looking on how to request headers at the Amazon Product Advertising API Documentation, and they were providing me the URL Parameters, however, what I would like to do is to set up the header so I can put the keys and values of the AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecretKey, and the Associate Tag Id, and then use the request library on Python to scrape the data, the reason for why I would like to set up the keys is to extract data with authorization. Please correct me if I am wrong in any way

Comment: You never put the AWSSecretKey anywhere in a request, including headers.  The API requests must be signed, and the signing information goes in the query string or the request body.  You need to generate requests that are consistent with the practices documented in the [API Reference for Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RequestAuthenticationArticle.html).  It's not clear, but it appears that you have concluded that there's a different solution, not mentioned in the documentation.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I was thinking of putting the AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecretKey, and the Associate Tag Id and then use something like BeautifulSoup to scrape data but with their authorization since they say that scraping data from their website is illegal, however, it is not stated in the API Documentation, I was just thinking of doing that

Comment: Well, that isn't how the API expects you to present your credentials.  Each request must be signed, as indicated in the docs.  The signing process is not difficult to implement.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How would I implement with Python. I tried to use `amazon-simple-product-api` but when I tried to lookup for an item it gave that error: `raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>`.